# Java NumberFormat For Persian(or Arabic) Digits

Tags: java, number-formatting

In a web based application, we want to change the number format in fa_IR locale. (The Unicode of digits in Persian and Arabic are different than Latin digits). The java does not support this feature ( For swing base applications you can use shaped digits http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/shapedDigits.html)

Anyway, this formater will replace the ASCII digits with unicode Persian digits. The algorithm is simple and make below replacement

```
0 >>>> \u06F0
1 >>>> \u06F1
2 >>>> \u06F2
3 >>>> \u06F3
4 >>>> \u06F4
5 >>>> \u06F5
6 >>>> \u06F6
7 >>>> \u06F7
8 >>>> \u06F8
9 >>>> \u06F9
```

Although we can write a simple converter and call it every time before showing the digits to user, we are looking for better solution. We want to extend the Java Locale and add new NumberFormate to it.

We believe with this approach we will have the Persian numbers displayed with Persian digits AND still we will have other number format options too. For example, #0.0## to format a number.

Please let me know how can we extend the java number format and register it to fa_IR?!
Also please let me know if my assumption about formatting is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this using the Locale Sensitive Services SPI: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/services.html